# What version of Adobe Photoshop is this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have Adobe Photoshop **CS6** version 13.0 x32. I am reading an [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/241074018_Evaluating_the_Quality_of_Commercial_ICC_Color_Management_Software) that found a bug in the rendering intent in Photoshop **6.0.1** which was fixed in Photoshop 7.
Are these the same version of Photoshop (CS6 and 6.0.1), i.e. do I have this bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Photoshop 6.0.1 is not the same version as Photoshop CS6. Photoshop CS6 is also known as Photoshop 13. You can also see that the article you reference is from 2002. Photoshop CS6 didn't come out till 2012.

Comment: Thanks so much. You just saved me an unnecessary software purchase!